# Android Asynctask loading resources in background and pass them back to main activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im quite new to android and now i need help with the asynctask, because i cannot get the rid of it ! I have some resources in my app which take 2-3 seconds to load and therefore i want to make a progressdialog with "please wait" and load the resources in the background with doinbackground and then pass them back to the main activity. I have read a lot of posts but it is not possible for me to get a solution

So i hope anybody can help me and tell me too how to pass the data back to the main activity. Thanx in advance !!

Here is the code :

```js
public class Menu extends Activity {
 
 MyTask objMyTask;
 
 Context context = this;
 LinearLayout order;
 ImageButton startorder;
 LinearLayout menu, categories_list;
 TextView texthint;

 String[] item_image;
 String[] item_title;
 String[] item_shortdesc;
 String[] item_desc;
 String[] item_price;
 int[] item_category;

 String[] MenuCategories;
 String sign = "";

 ArrayList<Integer> items_in_order = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 TextView buy;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
//force portrait
  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

 
  
  
  //load data from strings.xml
  sign = getResources().getString(R.string.CurrencySign);
  item_title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ItemTitle);
  item_image = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ItemImage);
  item_desc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ItemDescription);
  item_shortdesc = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ItemShortDescription);
  item_price = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ItemPrice);
  item_category = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ItemCategory);
  MenuCategories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MenuCategories);
  

  //load resources
  TextView menu_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu_title);
  TextView yourorder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourorder);
  TextView hinttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hinttext);
  TextView categories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categories);
  menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuscroll);
  startorder = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.startorder);
  order = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.orderscroll);
  texthint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hinttext);
  categories_list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.categories_list);
      
      
      I want load the data from strings.xml in background like item_title, item_image,item_desc, item_shortdesc, item_price, item_category, MenuCategories
      
      
      I have this code for asynctask: 
        
      
        
        public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     private ProgressDialog dialog;
     
  
  
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
      dialog = new ProgressDialog(Menu.this);
         dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
         dialog.show();
     }
      
    
     @Override
     
   
     protected String doInBackground(String... passing) {
  
      
      {
          try {
           
          I don´t  know what to enter here ?? 
           
          } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("Image","Failed to load Data",e);
          }
   
          return null;
      }    
     }
     
     @Override
 
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      
      
      if (dialog.isShowing()) {
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
      
    
      
 }
```

Comment: it takes 2-3 seconds to load some strings? uhm.. are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Resources are loaded by means of Resource Manager and, unlike with assets, the application has little control of this process. Calling `getResources().getString()` does not load the `strings.xml` file, as it's already been loaded based behind the scenes (once per app run). Thus, there is no point in placing these calls in AsyncTask.

You can learn more about accessing resources here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If your app isn't able to load your String resources quickly, probably your arrays are too big to be saved in resources. I strongly recommend you to use a SQLite database instead for your approach. That would fix your speed problem, and will be much more maintainable to use as your Menu increases.